# How to insert an image into Latex IEEE document by using miktex?

Tags: graphics, ieeetran

I wish to include my `1.png` image into the LaTeX document, however I get the error when using the command as below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics{1.png}
\caption{Figure 1: A picture of the same gull looking the other way! }
\label{fig:verticalcell}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../pdf/}{C:\Users\User\Desktop\IEEE_CS_Latex\1.png}}
```

Here is my path: C:\Users\User\Desktop\IEEE_CS_Latex\1.png

Updated:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \includegraphics{\graphicspath{1.png}
\caption{Figure 1: A picture of the same gull looking the other way! }
\label{fig:verticalcell}
\end{figure}
```

Updated 2:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{1}
% where an .eps filename suffix will be assumed under latex, 
% and a .pdf suffix will be assumed for pdflatex; or what has been declared
% via \DeclareGraphicsExtensions.
\caption{Simulation Results}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
```

Updated 3:
[image]

Updated 4:

```
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
\graphicspath{{../1/}{../png/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png}
\else
% or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
% will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
% driver is specified.
% \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
% declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
% \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
% and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
% every instance of \includegraphics
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at: 
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics/
% Another good source of documentation is "Using Imported Graphics in
% LaTeX2e" by Keith Reckdahl which can be found as epslatex.ps or
% epslatex.pdf at: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/
%
% latex, and pdflatex in dvi mode, support graphics in encapsulated
% postscript (.eps) format. pdflatex in pdf mode supports graphics
% in .pdf, .jpeg, .png and .mps (metapost) formats. Users should ensure
% that all non-photo figures use a vector format (.eps, .pdf, .mps) and
% not a bitmapped formats (.jpeg, .png). IEEE frowns on bitmapped formats
% which can result in "jaggedy"/blurry rendering of lines and letters as
% well as large increases in file sizes.
%
% You can find documentation about the pdfTeX application at:
% http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Also, what specifically is the error? Most likely, you need to add only `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble and then the `\includegrapics{1.png}` will work as long as your `.tex` file is in the same directory as the `1.png` file

Comment: I have added \usepackage{graphicx} to the 1st sample, while my image directory same with my .tex file, but I still cannot get the output, I have include this \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: You should change backslashes of the into slashes, even if in your OS path is with backslashes.

Comment: I have edited my ans as above, where do I get wrong? Can give me a complete code to get the figure? This is my first time using Latex.

Comment: Please see thecomment above: your examples are still not useful to diagnose the error.  The first example is OK but just a fragment, and not the source of an error. the second code section uses `\ ` instead of `/` as the path separator so will generate an error, but not the one shown the third "updated" example is missing `\begin{document}`  the "updated 2" example is like the first, just a fragment and not the source of error and the screenshot  shows an error unrelated to any of those or to graphics inclusion, you have a document with two `\documentclass` lines (the second one on line  552)

Comment: If you are using IEEEtrans draft option then change the option to draftcls and it will work since the draft option has a problem in rendering images

Answer (score 7):

In general, when including graphics in LaTeX you should:

- Not give the file extension (the range of known extensions will be tried automatically)
- Use only relative paths, and ideally not do that where you load the graphic
- Use slashes for paths *even* on Windows

For the common case of a graphic in the same directory (folder), this means things are usually as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{1}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where the `figure` environment is needed to allow floating and captioning (but not required to insert a figure 'here': a common misunderstanding).

Another common case is having figures in a subdirectory of the main document directory: something like `figures`, `graphics`, ...:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{1}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice that `\graphicspath` is used in the preamble, and that each path should be included in braces and use `/` for subdivision and at the end. (Not everyone is keen on `\graphicspath`, but for the case I've outlined of a per-document figures directory it works well in my opinion).

These instructions apply to most document classes (a few odd ones deliberately mess with parts of this process, but they are unusual and really not well designed, in general!).

Comment: my graphic is in the same directory (folder), i have tried, but I get the error as above (updated 3)

Comment: @user3340270 My demo is a _complete_ file: you can't paste it part way through a your 'real' document. You will need to adapt examples: here, you need the `figure` environment in the body of your document. (In general, it's normal to give 'self contained' examples: trying to edit to whatever one person has at one point in their document is simply not workable in general.)

Comment: I have the GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES as above, how do I get my figure in pdf file?

Comment: @user3340270 You really shouldn't, in general, add much beyond `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your preamble, perhaps followed by a `\graphicspath` line such as `\graphicspath{{../1/}{../png/}}`. All that is then needed in the document body is `\includegraphics` as I've shown. You really should start with a short 'testing' document until you are clear on this: LaTeX is non-trivial to use and you will get on much better learning stepwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
```

Use these lines. These lines are commented in IEEE sample LaTeX file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to get the required figure instead of square box, named with figure name, very simple: just use IEEE format in 'conference mode', i.e `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` instead of 'draft mode' `\documentclass[draft]{IEEEtran}`. I am using like that and it's working 100%.